# Regex for augmented assignment operation using positive look-ahead or look-behind

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, augmented-assignment

I have used the following regular expression to search and match augmented assignment operators:

```
AUG_ASSIGN = r'\+=|\-=|\*=|@=|/=|%=|/@=|&=|\|=|\^=|\<\<=|\>\>=|\*\*=|//='
```

I have a hunch that it is possible to eliminate the multiple occurrences of '=' using positive look-ahead or positive look-behind. So, my first search was the grammar section in Python reference manual. Even there, '=' is occurring multiple times:

```
augop:           "+=" | "-=" | "*=" | "/=" | "%=" | "**="
               | ">>=" | "<<=" | "&=" | "^=" | "|="
```

Understandable, as standard BNF does not include positive look-ahead or look-behind.

Next, I went through the suggestions given by SO itself, as I typed this question and my searches did not get me near my intended meeting point. Is it possible to shrink the expression to something like:

```
AUG_ASSIGN = <set of all binary operators>(?=\=)
```

Comment: ...why not just `(\+|-|\*|@|/|%|...)=`? No lookarounds required.

Comment: `(?:[-+*/@&%^|]|[<>/*]{2})=`

Comment: Beware, if you try to do serious parsing simple regexes are not enough. Think of the following: `txt = "An augmented assignment example is a += b". As it is enclosed in a litteral string (could even be a multi-line one...), it shall not be parsed.

Comment: And anyway, BNF if perfectly able to do that without look-ahead nor look-behind tricks

    `simple_op:           "+" | "-" | "*" | "/" | "%" | "**"
                       | ">>" | "<<" | "&" | "^" | "|"`
    `augop:                simple_op "="`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the single characters in a character set, and alternate with the other options which have two of the same character, so you can put them in a character set too (inside a group so that the same character can be matched again with a backreference). Put all of the above in a group, and end with `=`:

```
(?:[+\-*@&/%^|^]|([*/><])\1)=
```

https://regex101.com/r/JA84zS/4

No lookaround needed.

Comment: Nice. It is a new learning to me that '*' does not have to be escaped, as your expression works perfectly as endorsed by regex101.com. Will wait for other answers before accepting yours. However, I have passed my appreciation to your response.

Comment: It's only because it's in a character set - *most* characters don't have to be escaped in a character set. (I think the only exceptions are the string's delimiters, and backslashes)

Comment: And the range indicator '-', if it is to be seen as minus sign. Or, not? @anubhava has given a comment without it and it's working fine

Comment: Doesn't this regex also captures extra unintended strings like *>= >*= *<= <*= etc. so to be little more precise we could use this (?:[+\-*@&/%^|]|>>|<<|\*\*|//)= instead?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Ah, good point, thanks. Another way to do it, keeping the code DRY, would be to capture the character set in a group, and backreference it. https://regex101.com/r/JA84zS/4